# Multiply each row of a matrix with another matrix in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I want to multiply each row of a matrix with another matrix using tensorflow. For example:

```
A = [1,2,3 ; 4,5,6]

B = [1,1,1 ; 2,2,2 ; 3,3,3]
```

Multiplying each row of A to whole matrix B, then resulting tensor should be

```
C = [[1,2,3 ; 2,4,6 ; 3,6,9],
     [4,8,12 ; 5,10,15 ; 6,12,18]]
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Array broadcasting is what you want:

```
A2 = tf.reshape(A, (2, 3, 1))
B2 = tf.reshape(tf.transpose(B), (1, 3, 3))
C = A2 * B2
```

Any dimension with length 1 will automatically get broadcast to the appropriate length for element-wise multiplication, so `C` would have shape `(2, 3, 3)`.

I'm not 100% sure how to interpret your notation, so I may have got the axis order mixed up, in which case play around with the orders and/or removing the transpose.